# Is it safe to do const std::string& str = "" as default param for a function?

Tags: c++, string, std

```
struct StrHolder {
    std::string str;

    StrHolder(const std::string& _str = "")
    {
        str = _str;
    }
};
```

Simple question, is this safe??

Just a question, check code above.

Comment: What does "safe" mean to you?

Comment: And why do you think it might be not safe?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Presumably it means can it invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @user16217248 is correct, I want to know whether this can invoke UB...

Comment: Everything in C++ can be twisted into producing undefined behavior. Save a pointer to this parameter, and use it after the original temporary goes out of scope.

Comment: As used *in your example*, yes, it's ok.

Comment: Side note: prefer initializing members using the constructors initialization list rather than the constructor body, when you can (and here you can) : `StrHolder(const std::string& _str = "") : str(_str) {}`

Answer (score 1):

If you're unsure, I recommend overloading instead:

```
StrHolder() = default;

StrHolder(const std::string& str)
    : str(str)
{
}
```

This way there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

> Simple question, is this safe?? ... I want to know whether this can invoke UB

It is perfectly safe, and will not invoke undefined behavior.